# how to build and run a group of docker containers dynamically?

Tags: docker

I have an API server which writes some data to the DB and should eventually generate other containers - according to the different parameters it gets.
How should I do that? both in development and in production.

Comment: As a general rule, you don't; the overhead of starting a container is non-zero, and in standard Docker you can't do this without having unrestricted root access to the whole system.

Answer (score 0):

You need to work on a dockerfile generator. Like [here](https://www.startwithdocker.com/).

Thats a lot of work for your cause, but worth doing it. Friendly advise, have a control on the number of containers you create by reusing them for similiar functions.